# Error in Build.gradle For use com.android.supprot:design:29.0.0

Tags: java

When I use `com.android.supprot:design:29.0.0`, I have this error:

[image]

**app-level build.gradle**:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alifood"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:4.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'

    implementation 'com.cuberto:liquid-swipe:1.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.0"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your dependency declaration:

```
com.android.support:design:28.0.0
```

not

```
com.android.supprot:design:29.0.0
```

And its version **28.0.0**, not **29.0.0**. See [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#design).

Moreover, you should convert to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) which is replacing support libraries no longer being maintained.